# OLEDB CASE WHEN in SELECT Query

Tags: sql, oledb, ms-jet-ace

How can use `case when` statement with oledb to excel file ?
Like `select prodid, case prodid when 1 then 'fine' when 2 then 'good' end`

Comment: Is your Caps Lock or Shift key stuck?

Comment: need select query to read excel file

Comment: is this won't support even for Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 ?

Answer (score 4):

OLEDB is only a "relay" of sort and merely repeats the query to the underlying source.

I don't believe Excel supports the CASE WHEN construct, and thence you cannot use it, even through OLEDB.

You can instead use an Excel-specific idiom, the [**IIF() function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), as described in CodeByMoonlight's answer.  As noted the need to nest IIF() calls makes is a rather messy proposal for situations that require more than 3 or 4 cases.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to use IIF instead of CASE when querying Excel, eg

SELECT prodid, IIF(prodid = 1, 'fine', IIF(prodid = 2, 'good', ''))
FROM MyExcel

As you can see, it can get messy quickly. It's not too bad if you've only got a two-way evaluation, but in your code it's not clear whether you only have 2 possible values for prodid or more than that. My example assumes there are other values, hence the nested IIF.