# SubCount Divided By Total Count

Tags: sql, excel, vba

The table is named [Sheet1$]

We are working with the first column, [F1], which is populated with random numbers ranging in value from 1-20. The entire column, all 1,048,576 rows, are filled.

I want to find the percentage of rows with a value of 19

I can make separate subqueries and divide:

```
"Select Count([F1]) From [Sheet1$] Where [F1]=19;"
```

divided by

```
"Select Count([F1]) from [Sheet1$]
```

But I want to fit both queries into a single query.

EDIT:

It looks like the OLEDB precludes the use of CASE WHEN statements, but we can use IIF() statemnts

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1742005/9721351

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare PtrSafe Function timeGetTime Lib "winmm.dll" () As Long

Sub main()
Dim started As Long
Dim ended As Long
    Dim cn                                  As ADODB.Connection
    Dim abcCount                            As Long
    Dim pbcCount                            As Long
    Dim strFile                             As String
    Dim filePath                            As String
    Dim inputDirectoryToScanForFile         As String

    started = timeGetTime

    filePath = "Z:\Test\Test1.xlsx"

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

        cn.Open _
                "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                "Data Source='" & filePath & "';" & _
                "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=No;IMEX=1;"";"

        Debug.Print findCount(cn)

        cn.Close
        Set cn = Nothing

    ended = timeGetTime
    Debug.Print "Sum found in " & (ended - started) / 1000 & " seconds"
End Sub

Function findCount(ByRef cn As ADODB.Connection) As Long
    On Error GoTo CleanFail:
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    strSql = "Select Count([F1]) from [Sheet1$] where [F1]=19;"
    rs.Open strSql, cn
    findCount = rs.GetString
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Function
CleanFail:
    Debug.Print "nothing in file"
End Function
```

Comment: you might be able to do it with something along the lines of  `SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [F1] = 19) / SUM(CASE WHEN [F1] != '' ) FROM ... `  https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1543382/How-to-divide-by-a-subquery?PageIndex=[0]

Comment: If all 1,048,576 rows are populated, why can't you use that as denominator directly? Select Count([F1])*100.0/1048576 from [Sheet1$] where [F1]=19

Comment: @DIWP trying to develop a universal method. also want to learn. ideally would be able to do this with a single select statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT SUM(IIF([F1] = 19, 1 ,0)) *100.0 / SUM(IIF([F1] <> Null,1,0)) from [Sheet1$]

Comment: appreciate it but apparently OLEDB does not allow case when statements. See edit in OP

Comment: simple to convert to IFF then..see above edited answer now.