# Include records even when SQL where clause condition is not matched where SQL query is used for Excel

Tags: sql, excel, automationanywhere

I have a SQL query for Excel which works fine but when condition is not matched it skips that particular record. I need that record with cell value as `NULL`. how do I achieve this?. Below is the query:

```
Select [Supplier Code], [Policy Buyer] from [$vPolicyBuyerSheetName$$] where [Supplier Code] = "$vOutputSupplierCode$"
```

`vOutputSupplierCode` is taken from different Excel file, i am searching that value in `vPolicyBuyerSheetName` to get `[Supplier Code]`, `[Policy Buyer]`. I need `[Supplier Code]`, `[Policy Buyer]` even when `where [Supplier Code] = "$vOutputSupplierCode$"` is not satisfied.
This code is written in Database command of `AutomationAnywhere` tool for **Excel**.

I have tried `CASE` statement of SQL but no luck, error which I see using `CASE` is

```
"- Unrecognized keyword WHEN." 
Select [Supplier Code], [Policy Buyer] CASE WHEN [Supplier Code] = "$vOutputSupplierCode$" THEN [Policy Buyer] ELSE "null" END from [$vPolicyBuyerSheetName$$]
```

Answer (score 1):

The SQL engine tells you what the problem is:

```
Unrecognized keyword WHEN
```

When querying Excel files you are most likely using the ACE OLEDB driver, that one doesn't support `CASE WHEN` syntax, you need to use the `IIF()` function instead. If you have MS Access, you can use it to build and test your SQL there, quite convenient if you are not used to the limited SQL of ACE OLEDB.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741939/oledb-case-when-in-select-query) for same question.

Comment: SELECT IIf([Supplier Code] = "$vOutputSupplierCode$", [Supplier Code], "False") FROM [$vPolicyBuyerSheetName$$] - i tried this but it is returning false and is returning all records from [$vPolicyBuyerSheetName$$] file. 
I want SupplierCode in output excel, if a value "$vOutputSupplierCode$" exist in [$vPolicyBuyerSheetName$$] file. 
If a value "$vOutputSupplierCode$" doesn't exist [$vPolicyBuyerSheetName$$] file then i want to write in excel as NULL or False.