# VBA SQL IIF LIKE

Tags: sql, vba, adodb

I am trying to search for keywords in column "Remarks 1" and return a string if found and another if nothing found.

I have the below code that is working but cannot get the IIF to work without error:

```
"IIF([Remarks 1] Like '%Pizza%','Pizza','Other') AS [Desc2], " _
```

(I need to later groupby this column)

Additionally: can I nest the IFF to search for other keywords?

*ERROR: You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'iif([Remarks 1] ALike '%Pizza%','Pizza','Other') as part of an aggregate function*

```
Sub MacroTest()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

ws2.Cells.ClearContents

ws2.Range("A1").Value = "Account Name"
ws2.Range("B1").Value = "Account Number"
ws2.Range("C1").Value = "Currency"
ws2.Range("D1").Value = "Description"
ws2.Range("E1").Value = "Credit Amount"
ws2.Range("F1").Value = "Debit Amount"

Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\Users\username\Desktop\Test1.xlsx;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

    objRecordset.Open "SELECT [Account Name], " _
                            & "[Account Number], " _
                            & "[Currency], " _
                            & "[Description], " _
                            & "SUM([Credit Amount])," _
                            & "-SUM([Debit Amount])," _
                            & "IIF([Remarks 1] Like '%Pizza%','Pizza','Other') AS [Desc2] " _
                        & "FROM [Sheet1$] " _
                            & "GROUP BY [Account Name], " _
                                     & "[Account Number], " _
                                     & "[Currency]," _
                                     & "[Desc2]," _
                                     & "[Description]", _
    objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

ws2.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset objRecordset

End Sub
```

Comment: Learn to use parameters!

Comment: Start with replacing the mysql-style grave accents around your column names with square brackets, double quotes around string literals - with [single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1742067/11683), and removing the trailing comma after the last selected column.

Comment: Edits made as per GSerg's suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use an expression that is not part of an aggregation. Could you instead try like this:

```
objRecordset.Open "SELECT [Account Name], " _
                            & "[Account Number], " _
                            & "[Currency], " _
                            & "[Description], " _
                            & "SUM([Credit Amount])," _
                            & "-SUM([Debit Amount])," _
                            & "[Desc2] " _
                        & "FROM (" & _
                        "SELECT [Account Name], [Account Number], [Currency], [Description], [Credit Amount]," & _
                              " [Debit Amount], IIF([Remarks 1] Like '%Pizza%','Pizza','Other') AS [Desc2]" & _
                        " FROM [Sheet1$] ) tmp" _
                            & "GROUP BY [Account Name], " _
                                     & "[Account Number], " _
                                     & "[Currency]," _
                                     & "[Desc2]," _
                                     & "[Description];"
```

PS: Probably it is a better idea to use ACE.Oledb driver than Jet at this time.

Comment: does ACE.Oledb require me to install the MS Access Redistributable? - I would like to avoid installing on end-user machines

Comment: JET would also require it, no? What you need to install is the driver, not the access itself.

Comment: for some reason I can only use Jet :'( no install. I've marked your answer as correct